# Custom field name in ECharts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts, c3.js, echarts

I designed a console app. User can create report widgets (also selecting graph type, line, pie, etc...) and link to rest api functions. Then system binds rest api data (i don't know the data fields, user typing names in the screen) with report widgets and also related graphs.

I'm using D3.js for live dashboard (contains report widgets). But D3.js is not good choise for dynamic reports and dynamic ajax data. Because D3.js implemantation differs from chart to chart, it is not developer friendly like highcharts, echarts.

But highcharts, echarts and other charts' field name is not configurable. In [Kendo](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart) it can be done like this:

```
series: [
    { field: "price" }
  ]
```

Is there any way to do this in HighCharts or eCharts.
Or
Can you suggest any other chart libraries (prefer free/open source)?

UPDATE:
I'm not using eCharts any more. C3.js is more stable and easy to use. C3.js has same problem, but now i prepare custom data array and it is working.

```
chart.graph.load({
   columns: [
       GetTextData(serieData, "x"),
       SerializeDataWithSerieName("blabla", serieData)
   ]
});
....
function GetTextData(data, textToInsertStart) {
     var result = [];
     if (textToInsertStart)
         result.push(textToInsertStart);

     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        result.push(data[i][MyTextFieldName]);
     }
     return result;
}
....
function SerializeDataWithSerieName(serieName, data) {
     var result = [];
     result.push(serieName);
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        result.push(data[i][MyDataFieldName]);
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Comment: Cant you just bind the data fields manually and use a valid configuration object in Highcharts/eCharts?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: After json is received,parse it to a proper configuration object which is understandable for a charting library. How you parse the json will depend on the json structure and how you want to visualize the data.

Comment: Need more info on what that field is intended to do.

Comment: a data field. it can be count, average, price, etc...

Answer (score 1):

you can set options of your series but it's related on your series type

see below link for more details.

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/doc/doc-en.html#Series

```
series: [
    { name: "price" }
  ]
```

every thing about series are explained in more details in Echarts doc please visit the link you will find more .

Comment: name property of series is the text of specified data group. It is not the property of json data. I need to bind myJsonData.price field